# How to pass socket connection to other components in React Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, react-tsx

I have socket.io connection, I want to pass the original instance to other components. I am using Typescript React. It gives me error like:

```
Type '{ socket: Socket<DefaultEventsMap, DefaultEventsMap>; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.
  Property 'socket' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.ts(2322)
```

My code: main.tsx

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";
import "./index.css";
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

const socket = io("http://localhost:8081");

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")!).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App socket={socket}/> //getting error from socket
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would create a wrapper around the socket, something like this (the code is in typescript):

```
// Singleton
class MySocket {
   public socket:Socket;
   public static instance: MySocket = new MySocket();

   private constructor() {
      socket = io("http://localhost:8081");
   }

   public doSomething(){
      //...
   }

   public doOtherThings(){
      //...
   }
}
```

Then I would use it like this:

```
// Component A
const ComponentA = () => {
   useEffect(()=>{
      MySocket.instance.doSomething();
   },[]);
}

export default ComponentA
```

```
// Component B
const ComponentB = () => {
   useEffect(()=>{
      MySocket.instance.doOtherThings();
   },[]);
}

export default ComponentB
```

But, with your approach I think you can go this way:

```
interface Props {
   socket: Socket<DefaultEventsMap, DefaultEventsMap>
}
const App = (props:Props)=>{
}
```

and you should be able to pass the socket instance you are creating it in the main.tsx to the App component.

Comment: In your first method can I use `MySocket.instance.doOtherThings();` or `MySocket.instance.doSomething();` inside a function as well?

Comment: You can use whenever you need it. I put it inside of an `useEffect` just as an example. Edit: the private constructor of `MySocket` will run once, so only one connection will be created, no matter how many mounts/unmounts a component can have

Comment: Can you tell me why `MySocket` is running only once? Because, with the original instance its changing every time updates. So, should we need to follow this type of procedure when we need only one connection type scenario with any other libraries?

Comment: `MySocket` is a singleton. `MySocket.instance` returns the same instance of type `MySocket` every time it is called. It is desirable to reuse connections, like the one you have, because they are expensive to be created. That's why the socket connection is wrapped in a singleton, so we can reuse it in every component. Hope this clarifies the things for you

Comment: Can you please explain why this line `public static instance: MySocket = new MySocket();`  is not creating new instances every time?

Comment: "A static variable acts as a global variable and is shared among all the objects of the class. A non-static variables are specific to instance object in which they are created. Static variables occupies less space and memory allocation happens once. A non-static variable may occupy more space"